# PHP mail()- can't send mails to Gmail from localhost(xampp)

Tags: php, localhost, sendmail

For a school project I need to send e-mails from localhost to gmail.
I have downloaded and copied all of the files from http://glob.com.au/sendmail/ and pasted them into my xampp/sendmail folder.

Here are my settings which should technically work.

**sendmail.ini:**

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword
```

**php.ini:**

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
; SMTP = localhost
; smtp_port = 25
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you run sendmail.exe as an Administrator and in Compatibility Mode 'Windows XP (Service Pack 3)'. Right-click -> Properties -> Compatibility.
2. Then visit the following link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and Accept. Otherwise Gmail will block incoming requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xampp you can check this answer:
[[How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost][1])

Or you can use phpmailler instead of this method.